# What should I use instead of "aspect."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a sentence: "Another admirable aspect of Mr. Tanimoto is that he went to America several times with hopes of raising money for his church." I don't want to use the word "aspect" because it doesn't make sense. What word should I use.

Comment: Perhaps *quality*?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use 'aspect' if you point out something in particular about Mr. Tanimoto.

Concrete action:
"Another admirable ***aspect*** of Mr. Tanimoto's ***dedication to his parish*** is that he went to America several times with hopes of raising money for his church."

Abstract action:
"Another admirable ***aspect*** of Mr. Tanimoto's ***way of thinking*** is that he went to America several times with hopes of raising money for his church."